# color overlay on a div behavior

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm experiencing some odd behavior and I'm hoping some one here can explain my results.

I have two columns with text inside that have different background images and I'm trying to put color overlays on each.

The blue column is working properly, as the text is at full opacity over the blue overlay. The white block, however, alters the opacity of the text.

i have a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so2c0k4x/) (sans background images) that shows the behavior. I'm unsure why the behavior is different when the CSS is exactly the same with the exception of the color of the overlay. Can someone shed some light on this behavior?

html

```css
.white:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.88;
}

.blue:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #002b5d;
  opacity: 0.88;
}

.white,
.blue * {
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #152e54;
}

.a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #152e54;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.k {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.l {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 189x;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row sec">
  <div class="col-md-6 blue promo-cont">
    <h1 class="k">Mario Cart World Championships</h1>
    <h2 class="l">Split 10 Million Points</h2>

    <p class="p"> November 3 &amp; 4 - Win your share of 10 Million Points!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 white promo-cont">
    <h2 class="b">1 Million Estimated Prize Pool</h2>
    <h1 class="a">Zelda Cup Challenge</h1>

    <p class="">Racing’s premier tournament. Play online !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/so2c0k4x/

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `*` selector here

```
.white,
.blue * {
  position: relative;
}
```

The text with white background is not receiving `position: relative` and has no stacking context as a result.

Comment: thanks! I can't believe I've been done in by a typo.